# Is my Login Script is vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

2 days ago, a hacker got into a Admin Account. He told us that `login.php` is vulnerable.

But I can't find out how as I escaped the inputs:

```
$salt      = '78sdjs86d2h';
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($DB_H, addslashes($_POST['username']));
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($DB_H, addslashes($_POST['password']));
$hash1 = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
$hash = strtoupper($hash1);

$check = mysqli_query($DB_H, "SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name='$username' && Password = '$hash'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($check) != 0)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me , although you can improve it .. read php docs it will help you a lot

Comment: Maybe the hacker guessed the password? Or it's some other part of the code

Comment: In addition to what YourCommonSense said, you should probably learn [how to safely store a password](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using [some peculiar encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705324/how-to-create-a-sql-injection-attack-with-shift-jis-and-cp932), the code you posted, although it makes very little sense, is **invulnerable** to SQL injection. It will rather don't let a honest user to login, but there is no way to hack it through SQL injection.

The vulnerability were of the other kind, XSS for example.

Comment: They're also double-escaping, which is *weird*.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use prepare statements to avoid sql injection. For example

```
 $check = mysqli_query($DB_H, "SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name='$username' && Password = '$hash'")
```

use it like this

```
 $check = $DB_H->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name=? && Password = ?")
 $check->bind_param('ss',$username,$hash);
 $check->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with this:

```
$sHost = 'localhost';
$sDb = 'test';
$sUser = 'user';
$sPassword = 'password';

$oDb = new PDO("mysql:host={$sHost};dbname={$sDb}", $sUser, $sPassword);

$salt = '78sdjs86d2h';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$hash1 = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
$hash = strtoupper($hash1);

$sSql = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name = :username AND Password = :password';

$oStmt = $oDb->prepare($sSql);
$oStmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$oStmt->bindParam(':password', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($oStmt->execute()){
    $oRow = $oStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if(false === $oRow){
        echo 'User or password not valid';
    } else {
        echo 'Uer and password valid!!!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of these `mysqli` functions go for using PDO statements. Here is reference
[PHP PDO Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I'm trying to use it but its always giving me 500 error :( i can't use that i have no idea why ...

Comment: I deleted it 1 hour ago after many fails, now i really have no idea what to do ... that guy said 'the login.php script is the one vulnerable' .. but as can you guys said 'its seems fine' ...what should i do to stop the 'sql injection' ?..

Comment: The real question is why OP's code would be vulnerable? (if it is at all)